# Error:(107, 9) java: cannot find symbol symbol: method loadConfiguration()?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I'm trying to make a bukkit plugin and I get these errors when I try to build the artifact into a jar.

```
    Error:(107, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method loadConfiguration()
  location: class net.minenite.warzairdrops.MainClass

    Error:(117, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method log(java.lang.String,java.util.logging.Level)
  location: class net.minenite.warzairdrops.MainClass


    Error:(120, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method log(java.lang.String,java.util.logging.Level)
  location: class net.minenite.warzairdrops.MainClass
```

Heres my code:

[Main Class](https://pastebin.com/yVAXadhq)

[CommandsClass](https://pastebin.com/yJE11ZeT)

Comment: code needs to be posted here.

Comment: oh ok sorry will fix.

Comment: MainClass has no method `loadConfiguration()`. loggers usually accept level as 1st argument

Comment: I tried posting the code but it tells me: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.